# Convert API JSON format to data frame

Tags: arrays, json, r

Im trying to create a new subset data frame from this site using R.

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyr)

#source file
url = "http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1 q=nasa&domains=data.nasa.gov&offset=0&limit=500"

metadata <- fromJSON(url)
#Create a new data frame
nasa_api <- data.frame(id =  metadata$results$resource$id, 
                     title = metadata$results$resource$name,
                     description = metadata$results$resource$description,
                     download_count = metadata$results$resource$download_count,
                     domain_category = metadata$results$classification$domain_category,
                     link = metadata$results$link,
                     permlink = metadata$results$permalink)
```

I notice that metadata object contains nested lists. I need to create a new dataset for classifications which is a data frame nested inside metadata. So ideally I want this new data frame to contain "id" so that I can join these 2 datasets later.

I think it will be an easy task but I am new to R. Please can you help?

Comment: Can you post a subset of your JSON?  The URL is not working for me.  Also, it is helpful to illustrate an example of what ideal output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there is a problem in your URL (`v1 q=nasa` should be `v1?q=nasa`).  As such, I have illustrated how you might solve this problem with the `tidyjson` package.  It can be a lot of typing, but it gives you a solid *tidy* data_frame afterwards.  I recommend the [development version](https://github.com/jeremystan/tidyjson) from `devtools::install_github('jeremystan/tidyjson')`, which has some features not yet on `CRAN`.

In any case, since you did not articulate which nested arrays you are interested in, I just picked one (`classification/domain_metadata`).

```
## devtools::install_github('jeremystan/tidyjson')

library(dplyr)
library(tidyjson)

j <- as.tbl_json("http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?q=nasa&domains=data.nasa.gov&offset=0&limit=500")

base <- j %>% enter_object(results) %>% gather_array()

nasa_api <- base %>% spread_values(id = jstring(resource, id), title = jstring(resource, 
  name), description = jstring(resource, description), download_count = jstring(resource, 
  download_count), domain_category = jstring(classification, domain_category), 
  link = jstring(link), permlink = jstring(permlink))

print(nasa_api)
#> # A tbl_json: 500 x 9 tibble with a "JSON" attribute
#>          `attr(., "JSON")` document.id array.index        id
#>                      <chr>       <int>       <int>     <chr>
#>  1 "{\"resource\":{\"d..."           1           1 gvk9-iz74
#>  2 "{\"resource\":{\"d..."           1           2 scmi-np9r
#>  3 "{\"resource\":{\"d..."           1           3 gquh-watm
#>  4 "{\"resource\":{\"d..."           1           4 dtgb-tk9p
#>  5 "{\"resource\":{\"d..."           1           5 j6wr-4xhn
#>  6 "{\"resource\":{\"d..."           1           6 357b-ra7j
#>  7 "{\"resource\":{\"d..."           1           7 e2ud-kf5m
#>  8 "{\"resource\":{\"d..."           1           8 uwnx-gns8
#>  9 "{\"resource\":{\"d..."           1           9 fzmj-dfnj
#> 10 "{\"resource\":{\"d..."           1          10 szzb-kefa
#> # ... with 490 more rows, and 6 more variables: title <chr>,
#> #   description <chr>, download_count <chr>, domain_category <chr>,
#> #   link <chr>, permlink <chr>

## explore the json_types of one of the objects
base %>% enter_object("classification") %>% .[1, ] %>% gather_object() %>% json_types()
#> # A tbl_json: 5 x 4 tibble with a "JSON" attribute
#>           `attr(., "JSON")` document.id array.index            name
#>                       <chr>       <int>       <int>           <chr>
#> 1                        []           1           1      categories
#> 2                        []           1           1            tags
#> 3     "\"Management/Ope..."           1           1 domain_category
#> 4                        []           1           1     domain_tags
#> 5 "[{\"value\":\"\",\"k..."           1           1 domain_metadata
#> # ... with 1 more variables: type <fctr>

## example of an ancillary table
base %>% spread_values(id = jstring(resource, id)) %>% enter_object("classification") %>% 
  enter_object("domain_metadata") %>% gather_array("domain_metadata_id") %>% 
  spread_values(key = jstring(key), value = jstring(value)) %>% select(document.id, 
  array.index, id, key, value) %>% as_data_frame()
#> # A tibble: 6,343 x 5
#>    document.id array.index        id                                key
#>  *       <int>       <int>     <chr>                              <chr>
#>  1           1           1 gvk9-iz74          Common-Core_Contact-Email
#>  2           1           1 gvk9-iz74                Common-Core_License
#>  3           1           1 gvk9-iz74      Common-Core_System-of-Records
#>  4           1           1 gvk9-iz74           Common-Core_Program-Code
#>  5           1           1 gvk9-iz74           Common-Core_Described-By
#>  6           1           1 gvk9-iz74    Common-Core_Public-Access-Level
#>  7           1           1 gvk9-iz74 Common-Core_Temporal-Applicability
#>  8           1           1 gvk9-iz74        Common-Core_Is-Quality-Data
#>  9           1           1 gvk9-iz74               Common-Core_Language
#> 10           1           1 gvk9-iz74             Common-Core_References
#> # ... with 6,333 more rows, and 1 more variables: value <chr>
```